# How can I find the smallest value in an integer list?

Tags: sml

```
fun min [] = [] | min (h::t) = if h < (min t) then h else (min t)
```

Why the above gives an error??
Please help!
Thanks!

The error message:

```
stdIn:1.37 Error: overloaded variable not defined at type
    symbol: <
    type: 'Z list
```

Comment: @RB.
`stdIn:1.37 Error: overloaded variable not defined at type
  symbol: <
  type: 'Z list`
Sorry don't know why no line breaks here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of empty list, you return an empty list whose type is incompatible with type of elements such as `h` or `min t`.

A few corrections:

1. Empty list is an exceptional case where you don't have the smallest value. You should raise an exception e.g. `Empty`.
2. You forget a base case for lists consisting of only one element.

So the skeleton of the function would be:

```
fun min [] = raise Empty
  | min [x] = ...
  | min (x::xs) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to take advantage of option types in this case. You'll avoid having to handle exceptions, but will be forced to handle the NONE case properly wherever you're calling this function from.

```
fun smallest [] = NONE
  | smallest (x::xs) = case smallest xs of
                       NONE => SOME x
                     | SOME y => if x < y
                                 then SOME x
                                 else SOME y
```